# Creating a new user profile with the same user profile folder name

Tags: macos, user-account

If I want to revert macOS settings or maybe to fix some of its bugs, I may decide to create a new user profile.

My name is John and the name of my user profile folder is just that, `john`. That is, when creating a new user profile, I have two options:

- to give its folder a different name (e.g., `johndoe`),
- or get the old name of the user profile folder using a temporary user profile, that is, to create `john123`, log in, delete `john`, create fresh new `john`, log in into `john`, delete `john123`.

Is there a more straighforward way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User and directory names need to be unique, so you can‘t work around all the hassles here.

I probably would just create an additional admin account and use this to delete and recreate `john` whenever the need arises. Basically your second option, without the deletion of `john123` at the end.

If shell scripts are a thing for you, you could also automate the recreation by creating a shell script to do so, and run this from `john123`.